# Ajax call returns 0 when add_action is inside a class in functions.php

Tags: theme-development, ajax

Ajax call returns 0 as output. I am sure that hook is not working and it's not calling the `test2` method. Why is `add_action(...` not working inside class in `functions.php`?

--------Wrap inside `functions.php` Starts-------

```
class test{
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_test2', array( $this, 'test2' ) );
    }                       
    public function test1() { ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                var ajaxurl = "<?php echo get_site_url();?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
                var data = {'action':'test2'};
                 $.ajax({   
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    success: function(val) {
                        alert(val);
                    },
                }); 
            });             
        </script><?php 
    }               
    public function test2(){
        echo "success";
        exit;
    }       
}
```

--------Wrap inside `functions.php` Ends-------

Created an object in a template page and call to test1 method:

```
$ob_call = new test;
$ob_call->test1();
```

Comment: How does your object get created when the ajax call is made? It's not the same request you are making the call from.

Comment: Thanks for your response....i am not creating my object in ajax call, its created in my pages (Template).

$ob_call = new test; is located in my page when i am viewing my page its gets created

Comment: When your AJAX call is made there is no function hooked to that action, because there is no object. Your page and your AJAX call are two separate requests with no data persisting between the two. You must add your object on every request within your functions.php file.

Comment: Thanks milo....it works i have posted the answer below...

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203383/why-hooking-differs-in-plugin-and-function-php-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

While I am not sure why you want to do it like this, please find below the working code. Please note the comments in line. I hope this helps.

```
class test{
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_test2', array( $this, 'test2' ) );
        /* Front end ajax needs this. */
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_test2', array( $this, 'test2' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'test1' ) );
    }

    public function test1() {
      /* in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value */
      wp_localize_script('test-script-ajax', 'ajaxobj', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
      /* Moved your js to a separate js file and enquing it the WordPress way */ 
      wp_enqueue_script( 'test-script-ajax', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/test-ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ));
    }

    public function test2(){
        echo "success";
        exit;
    }
}

$ob_call = new test;
$ob_call->test1();
```

Here is the code in test-ajax.js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var data = { 'action':'test2' };
  jQuery.post( ajaxobj.ajaxurl, data, function( response ) {
            alert(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: >>Hi bro thanks for your response.... its not helping me, i have tried this sets of codes, Ajax call returns 0 its not returning success as i told before its not referring to test2 method.
>>Why i am not using wp_enqueue_script(... is that it takes java script  is external js file and i cant use php.
The same sets of code i tried to implement in plugin its working pretty good.
>>I want to know why its not working in function.php and i want to implement it in function.php.
>>I have posted the cods which i used it in plugin below, no space so i posted it in (Answer Your Question)

Comment: class test{
   public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'pro_ad ));
    add_menu_page( 'Pro-Cl', 'Pro-Cl', 'appo', 'pro-reg', array($this,'t1'));
    }  
  public function t1(){?>
   <script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      var ajaxurl = "<?php echo get_site_url();?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
        var data = 
        $.ajax({ 
         url:ajaxurl,
         type:"POST",
         data:{'action':'t2'},
         success:function(a) {alert(a);}
         });
        }); </script><?php 
  }
  public function t2(){
   echo "1";
   exit;
  }  
}
new t;

Comment: Can you please update your comment above so that its readable?

Comment: i had reached the maximum character provided for comments so i cant make the content clear, is there any alternative way to update it clearly....

Comment: which one is not clear to you first or second comment.

Comment: Second comment where you added code.

Comment: I have raised a new question about the Second Comment Kindly look to it at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203383/why-hooking-differs-in-plugin-and-function-php-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

It works now

----------**Function.php**---------------

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_test2', array( 'test', 'test2' ) );

class test{

    public function __construct() {
        
    }                       
    public function test1() { ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                var ajaxurl = "<?php echo get_site_url();?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
                var data = {'action':'test2'};
                 $.ajax({ 
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    success: function(val) {
                        alert(val);
                    },
                }); 
            });             
        </script><?php 
    }               
    public function test2(){
        echo "success";
        exit;
    } 
          
}
```

---

------------------page (**Template**)-------------

```php
$ob_call = new test;

$ob_call->test1();
```

Have a look to
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203383/why-hooking-differs-in-plugin-and-function-php-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Add `wp_die();` at the end the your function.

Comment: If you're already echoing something shouldn't the exit be enough? What's the benefit of using wp_die() instead?